# Retreiveing Bytecode of another smart contract through a smart contract

Tags: contract-deployment, bytecode

I am working on a project and I was wondering if its possible to retrieve the bytecode of another smart contract on Ethereum though my smart contract ?

So basically, I will have a copy of that smart contract, then I can process it in an off-chain solution.

Is this possible ?

Comment: You don't need a smart contract to grab the bytecode of a contract to process it off chain, you can directly grab it with eth_getCode. You probably want to save the cost of deploying the contract and go that way

Answer (score 2):

In solidity:

```
contract Foo {
  function foo(address bar) public view returns (bytes memory) {
    return bar.code;
  } 
}
```

The opcode is EXTCODECOPY